# VB Forms INSERT INTO statement, Changing Password Form

Tags: vb.net, vba, validation, ms-access, insert

Hey I'm working on a school project and have run into some issues

I'm trying to make a change password form. I have an access table called "tblLogin" with the columns Username, Password, SecQuest, SecAns, Level.

Username is a public variable which belongs in my login form

The program is currently not changing the value of password in the tblLogin table

I assume it's a problem with my INSERT INTO Statement

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim sql As String

    Dim Conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\Nelson\Documents\SystemDB\DB.accdb")
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim response As Integer

    Try


    Conn.Open()
    'establishes communication with the database
    sql = "SELECT Password FROM tblLogin WHERE Username = """ & LoginForm.username & """"
    'declares SQL statement
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
    'runs sql statement on database 
    da.Fill(ds, "passwordcheck")
    'fills in a dataset called "passwordcheck" with infomation selected by the sql statement

        If TextBox1.Text = TextBox2.Text And TextBox3.Text = TextBox4.Text And TextBox1.Text = ds.Tables("passwordcheck").Rows(0).Item(0) And TextBox1.Text <> "" And TextBox2.Text <> "" And TextBox3.Text <> "" And TextBox4.Text <> "" Then
            response = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Attention", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

            If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblLogin Password VALUES (?) WHERE Username = """ & LoginForm.username & """", Conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
                Conn.Close()
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Passwords entered are incorrect", "Attention")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Passwords entered are incorrect", "Attention")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PASSWORD is a reserved keyword for MS-Access. If you want to use it for column names then enclose in sqare brackets. Said that, please use parameterized query for your commands.

```
Conn.Open()
'establishes communication with the database
sql = "SELECT [Password] FROM tblLogin WHERE Username = ?"
'declares SQL statement
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, Conn)
da.SelectCommand("@p1", LoginForm.username)
.....
```

Finally the INSERT clause doesn't require a WHERE statement 
(it is meaningless set a condition to select some rows for an INSERT)

```
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblLogin [Password] " & _
                                "VALUES (?) "
```

But looking at your code, then probably you need an UPDATE instead of an INSERT

```
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblLogin " & _ 
                                "SET [Password] = ? WHERE Username ?"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TEXTBOXFORUSERNAME.Text
```

**--- AND THE MOST IMPORTANT LINE IS ---**

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Without this no attempt is made to update the database table

Comment: Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE tblLogin " & "SET [Password] = ? WHERE Username ?", Conn)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = LoginForm.username
Conn.Close()


This doesn't work, the password value in tblLogin doesn't change, have I made an error?